# How do i get specific content from JSON String?

Tags: php, json, trading

I'm trying to create a trading bot using an API class.
I'm trying to output the result of some calls to my API's functions, and the output should be a JSON string

I would like to get only one of the portions of my JSON string ($array["result"]), but I don't know how to do it.

My string is like this:

```
array(3) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["message"]=> string(0) "" ["result"]=> array(0) { } }
```

I've tried methods to extract content, but my JSON string looks different because i also output the value type, and the formatting is different because all the content is in the same line.

My code which creates the JSON is this:

```
  class BittrexxApi {

private $apiKey         = null;
private $apiSecret    = null;
private $apiVersion   = "1.1";
private $bittrexUrl   = "https://bittrex.com/api/";
private $baseUrl      = null;
private $version_major  = "0";
private $version_minor  = "3";
private $version  = "";


public function __construct($apiKey = null , $apiSecret = null)
{
    $this->apiKey     = $apiKey;
    $this->apiSecret  = $apiSecret;
    $this->baseUrl    = $this->bittrexUrl . "v" . $this->apiVersion . "/";
    $this->version    = $version_major . "." . $version_minor;
}

private function send($method = null , $args = array() , $secure = true) {
  if(empty($method)) return array("status" => false , "error" => "method was not defined!");

  if($secure) $args["apikey"] = $this->apiKey;
  $args["nonce"] = time();

  $urlParams  = array();
  foreach($args as $key => $val) {
    $urlParams[]  = $key . "=" . $val;
  }

  $uri  = $this->baseUrl . $method;

  $argsString = join("&" , $urlParams);
  if(!empty($urlParams)) {
      $uri  = $uri . "?" . $argsString;
  }

  $sign = $secure == true ? hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$this->apiSecret) : null;

  $uri = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $uri));
  $ch = curl_init($uri);
  if($secure) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $execResult = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_error($ch))
  {
      return array("status" => false , "error" => curl_error($ch));
  }

  $obj = json_decode($execResult , true);
  return $obj;

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want from it? `$array['success']`, `$array['message']` or `$array['result']`?

Comment: I would like the $array["result"]. I will edit the question now

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($execResult , true);`  You're aware that when you pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()`, you get an array, not an object, right? Also, you say "My string is like this".  What string? What exactly are you doing to get that output?

Comment: Its not json, the class method send returns an array, just access/view it like above `print_r($array['result'])` Suggest you read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I agree with Lawrence.  It looks to me like your sample string is output of var_dump, not json_encode.

Comment: The problem was I didn't know $obj = json_decode($execResult , true); returned an array instead of an object. Thank you very much now I solved removing the param "true".